# Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TFStringComparer' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, exception, microsoft-test-manager

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
```

I've encountered - **TypeLoadException was unhandled**

Error Description Says:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TFStringComparer' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is the DLL it's referencing? You checked you're not using an old bin or GAC reference?

Comment: placed the dll in bin

Comment: A re-install like @Patrick (or better upgrade) suggested is probably going to be the fastest way to solve this and provide a gaurentee that you'll start off on the right foot and won't run into further issues. I'd be interested to know if you use ILSpy if the type even exists in the DLL? Surely it does in the Nuget package which then points to a permission or corruption issue.

Comment: Did you use Nuget package manager? You should be referencing from the package folder not the bin folder

Comment: Does referencing path(package folder/bin folder) make difference?

Comment: Yes, you probably have the old DLL...

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson - I've referenced the dll from package folder. It dint make any difference. Same error exists

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) instead of [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.112.1). This resolved my error. Thanks @Patrick-MSFT, you provided me thoughts to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Base on error info, the solution is installing and  refer the necessary assemblies `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=15.0.0.0`.

You can install nugget Package [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.112.1). After installed this Package, you can use this reference in the code.

Another workaround is  copying the necessary assemblies from another machine. If the issue still persist, please re-install the VS 2017. More details please take a look at [this similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6f53636-04a5-43dd-bc23-ed5c5067ef2a/could-not-load-type-microsoftteamfoundationtestmanagementclientitestplanhelper2?forum=vsmantest).

Comment: Installed the nugget Package and refered **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common** in the code. Same error exists. Let me try re-installation of VS2015

Comment: I've re-installed VS2015 as suggested. Error exists. Do we have any alternate to resolve the issue? Please help/suggest